# Re-entrant functions and how it looks?

Tags: reentrancy

I don't really understand re-entrant code.

Can somebody show me an algorithm for re-entrant code so I can look at it? An explanation of how it works would be nice too. Thanks.

Comment: To give directions we need to know where you're starting from, and we don't know that. Was there a specific function you didn't understand? Can you show it to us? Do you know what “re-entrant” means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you, as a developer of some function, can be sure that your function is not called during its execution time, then you may not to pay attention to make it reentrant.

However if your function can be called from different task, threads, or just by interruption signal, there can be a situation, when the function reenters itself during its execution, if it is not reentrant-compliant , not protected from multiple entrances it may lead to unpredictable behaviour, such as data corruption\overwriting or corruption of chronology of the actions in the function.

Here may be a number of approaches. Sometimes it is enough to write a function, for example, working only with copies of the external variables. However sometimes using of mutexes is inevitable. When mutexes are used, the caller of the function will be waiting for mutex unlocking. You just place mutex locking before the critical section and mutex unlocking after the critical section. Whole function body can be wrapped between lock and unlock couple.